# why I got different result when I use weka,python and spark about linear regression?

Tags: scikit-learn, weka, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I have used weka and python about linear regression to predict the data about price.And I got the same result as the attachment.[linear-regression in weka](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSiMy.png)
[linear-regression in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpe0h.png)

The data I used to predict is like as follows:

ft,bed,bath,garage,age,price

1048,2,1,1,30,104900

1052,2,2,1,20,128750

1057,2,1,1,32,102900

1060,2,2,1,31,114900

1072,2,2,1,31,119500

1076,2,1,1,24,110500

But when I used spark(1.6) mllib to analysis this data, I got a different result. I have changed the values of interation and stepsize. But the result is far away from the result in weka and python.

I formated the data as following type.

104900,1048 2 1 1 30

128750,1052 2 2 1 20

102900,1057 2 1 1 32

And the code is like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionModel
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD

// Load and parse the data
val data = sc.textFile("/root/data/house.data")
val parsedData = data.map { line =>
  val parts = line.split(',')
  LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(parts(1).split(' ').map(_.toDouble)))
}.cache()

// Building the model
val numIterations = 2000
val stepSize = 0.00000001
val algorithm = new LinearRegressionWithSGD()
algorithm.setIntercept(true)
algorithm.optimizer.setNumIterations(numIterations)
algorithm.optimizer.setStepSize(stepSize)

val model = algorithm.run(parsedData)

println(model.weights)
println(model.intercept)
```

Comment: I have tried to normalized  the data like following format.                    (10.49,1.048 2 1 1 3)
(12.875,1.052 2 2 1 2)
(10.29,1.057 2 1 1 3.2)
(11.49,1.06 2 2 1 3.1)
(11.95,1.072 2 2 1 3.1)                                                             Moreover, I have tried different Stepsize and number of iteration which is large enough to get stable result. Unfortunately, I still get the result far away from weka and python.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that your `stepSize` is way too small.
To start with, try stepSize 0.1, check if your result changes.

Weka and Python use closed-form solution, therefore the results are identical. In Spark you iterate with StochasticGradientDescent, so the
result will not be identical, but should be close.

If the result is not even close, try to check your code on some very simple data. For example, for data like [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), ...] do you get intercept 0 and coefficient 1? Did you also check if everything is parsed correctly and how your RDD looks like?

Comment: Thank you for your replying. I have tried different stepSize from (10e-10 to 10e2),but I didn't get the suitable answer. Then I tried to format the data with nomalized the data like following format.                                                        10.49,1.048 2 1 1 3
12.875,1.052 2 2 1 2
10.29,1.057 2 1 1 3.2
11.49,1.06 2 2 1 3.1
11.95,1.072 2 2 1 3.1   I still did not get the suitable result.